# electron-packager spawn ENOENT

Tags: javascript, electron, spawn, enoent, electron-packager

I'm working on an electron app that controls gulp tasks via gui. You click on a task and it runs. Pretty simple stuff. On macOS, when I run npm start it runs just fine, but when I package it with electron-packager, I get this error:

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: spawn gulp ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

This is the code:

```
exports.runTask = (taskName, projPath) => {
    const cp = spawn('gulp', [ taskName ], {cwd: projPath});
    cp.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
    cp.stdout.on('data', data => {
        console.log(data);
        mainWindow.webContents.send('task-console-data', data);
    });

    cp.stderr.setEncoding('utf8');
    cp.stderr.on('data', data => {
        console.error(data);
        displayNotification({text: `[error] ${data}`});
        mainWindow.webContents.send('task-console-data', `[error] ${data}`);
    });

    cp.on('exit', code => {
        if (code === 0) {
          displayNotification({
            title: 'gulp',
            subtitle: 'Finished running tasks'
          });
        } else if ( !code || code === null ) {
            return;
        } else {
            console.error(`Exited with error code ${code}`);

            displayNotification({
                title: 'gulp',
                subtitle: `Exited with error code ${code}`,
                sound: 'Basso'
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case anyone else is running into this problem, the answer is to correct the $PATH. There is a package on npm that does this for you.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/fix-path

Answer (score 0):

You should forward the `process.env.PATH` to the spawn options because the `child process` environment variables is overriding in `options.env`. So the OS don't know exactly where to look your command `gulp`.

So you can do this:

```
const cp = spawn('gulp', [ taskName ], {
    cwd: projPath,
    env: {
        PATH: process.env.PATH,
    },
});
```